# How to delete mysql rows automatically using cron job in php?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I need to delete rows that passes 24 hours every day, but still not working properly is there any error in my code
cron command:

```
/usr/bin/php -q/home/mywebsite/public_html/folder/deleteafter24hours.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

php code:

```
$DeleteQuery = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `DatePOST` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)');
```

Comment: doesn't your code need to connect to the database or something before you can use that query?

Comment: sry for the error in writing, yes its connected to database @genisage

Comment: did you try this query in the mysql console? if it works there, then obviously the problem is not with the sql but the PHP, or permissions on the cron user or whatever

Comment: On this code not permision for connect to mysql, database,.... run on console and see results.

Comment: @Ahmad where is located your file deleteafter24hours.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in your .sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
 php /home/mywebsite/public_html/folder/deleteafter24hours.php
```

I suppose that your script is in /home/mywebsite/public_html/folder/

and then run your script from the shell

Comment: @Ahmad I edit my answer add to your .sh at first line this: #!/bin/sh and edit your question with your content of your .sh file

Comment: @Ahmad you got some advance?